# Como validar se um valor é uma tupla possuindo uma string e um inteiro?

Tags: python, funções

Quero escrever uma função que recebe um argumento (qualquer tipo) e devolve `true` se o argumento for um tuplo (elementos pares, duplos de 2), onde o 1º é um nome (`str`) e o 2º é uma idade (`int`). Em caso contrário devolve `False`.

O meu primeiro esboço:

```
def verifica(tuplo):

    tuplo = ( (joao,39), (paulo,15), (andre,14), (simao,21) )    

resultado = isinstance(tuplo[0],str)

return (isinstance(tuplo[0],str)    
return (isinstance(tuplo[1],int)
```

Sei que devo ter um ciclo `IF`. Ao invocar a função, não seria suposto ter 2 campos? Algo como nome e idade?

Ex: `verifica(joao,39)` - caso a combo esteja no tuplo, devolve um `true`?

Comment: Comece por confirmar a indentação do código, e altere-a para que fique exatamente igual à que você tem no seu editor.

Comment: Coloquei o código tal e qual como esta no meu editor. By the way, utilizo python 3.3 e Wing IDE 101 como compilador.

Comment: Parece-me improvável, pois da forma que o código está na pergunta, você tem `return` fora da função `verifica`. Logo eu assumo que seja tudo código da função `verifica` mas só você poderá confirmar.

Answer (score 3):

Vou partir da premissa que você esqueceu de colocar as aspas nas suas strings. Então a tupla correta seria:

```
(('joao', 39), ('paulo', 15), ('andre', 14), ('simao', 21))
```

A partir disso você precisa saber testar o tipo de uma variável corretamente. Você pode usar o método [`type()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) e comparar diretamente com o tipo que você quer, como por exemplo:

```
if type(variavel) == tuple:
    print('É uma tupla')
```

Porém vale lembrar que dessa maneira não há uma verificação de subclasses, ou seja, no exemplo acima, se `variavel` fosse de uma subclasse de `tuple` o print não seria executado pois não há checagem de subclasses.

Para realizar esta checagem basta usar o método [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance), que checa se a variável é do tipo perguntado ou se é de alguma subclasse do tipo perguntado. Exemplo:

```
if isinstance(variavel, tuple):
    print('É um tupla ou subclasse de tupla')
```

O uso de uma ou de outra vai depender dos requisitos do seu software, mas como uma regra geral eu utilizo `isinstance()` pois é bem provável que a subclasse se comporte como a classe pai.

Dito isso, tudo o que você precisaria fazer é testar os 4 requisitos que você quer, que são:

1. Variável é uma `tuple`
2. Esta tupla tem apenas dois elementos
3. Primeiro elemento da tupla é `str`
4. Segundo elemento da tupla é `int`

Você teria algo como:

```
def verifica(variavel):
    return isinstance(variavel, tuple) \
        and len(variavel) == 2 \
        and isinstance(variavel[0], str) \
        and isinstance(variavel[1], int)
```

Para fins de curiosidade, ao invés de usar `and` você pode usar o método [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) que retorna `True` apenas se todos os parâmetros recebidos também forem `True`. O exemplo completo ficaria assim:

```
def verifica(variavel):
    return all((
        isinstance(variavel, tuple),
        len(variavel) == 2,
        isinstance(variavel[0], str),
        isinstance(variavel[1], int)
    ))

dados = (
    ('joao', 39),     # True
    (b'andre', 14),   # False pois 1º elemento não é str
    ('paulo', 15.3),  # False pois 2º elemento não é int
    ('simao', 21, 0)  # False pois não contém exatamente 2 elementos
)

for d in dados:
    print(verifica(d))
```

<sup>[Repl.it com o código funcionando.](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/SpringgreenIllustriousExpertise)</sup>

---

**Edit**: adicionada a checagem de tamanho da tupla
(Sugestão: @anderson-carlos-woss).

---

**Edit 2**

Como ainda parecem haver dúvidas sobre como aplicar a função `verifica()` para todos os elementos de uma sequência, e não apenas a um elemento, vou elaborar.

A função `verifica()` recebe uma tupla e checa se o padrão da tupla está correto:

```
tupla_valida = ('Tupla válida', 0)
verifica(tupla_valida)  # True
```

Se você quer checar todas as tuplas de uma sequência, você pode percorrer esta sequência usando um laço `for` e testar uma por uma. Se algumas delas for `False` aí você escolhe o que o seu programa deve fazer a respeito disso.

Exemplo, checar se a sequência contém apenas tuplas válidas:

```
tuplas = (('joao', 39), ('paulo', 15), ('andre', 14), (0, 'Inválida'))

todas_validas = True  # Valor inicial

for tupla in tuplas:
    if not verifica(tupla):
        # se alguma tupla for inválida atribui False e sai do loop
        todas_validas = False
        break

if todas_validas:
    print("Todas as tuplas são válidas")
else:
    print("A sequência contém alguma tupla inválida")
```

<sup>[Repl.it com o código funcionando.](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/DarksalmonHeavenlyTest)</sup>

Se você tiver alguma dúvida do código acima, estude um pouco sobre o [`for`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) e o [`break`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops).

Vou deixar como exemplo para estudo, uma alternativa ao código anterior que usa o método [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) mencionado anteriormente e [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) para chegar ao mesmo resultado.

```
tuplas = (('joao', 39), ('paulo', 15), ('andre', 14), (0, 'Inválida'))

# aplica a função `verifica` em todos os elementos da tupla e passa
# a lista resultante para o método `all`
# nesse caso o método `all` recebe: (True, True, True, False)
todas_validas = all([verifica(tupla) for tupla in tuplas])

if todas_validas:
    print("Todas as tuplas são válidas")
else:
    print("A sequência contém alguma tupla inválida")
```

<sup>[Repl.it com o código funcionando.](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/MinorSimpleRegisters)</sup>

Comment: Fernando, agradeço a atenção que dispensou. Alguns pormenores para esclarecer. O objetivo é essencialmente é eu escrever verfica(('joao',15)) e caso essa condição esteja no tuplo.. ou seja o nome joao com o par de idadade 15, aí entao o progrma retorna o false.

Comment: Não posso utilizar prints, só mesmo return.

Comment: Você chegou a rodar o código? A função que escrevi faz exatamente isso... Você pode passar para ela `verifica(('João', 15))` e ela retornará `True` se for válido, ou `False` se for inválido.
O print é apenas para demonstração.

Comment: Acho que entendi... Quando você diz "caso a condição esteja no tuplo" você quer saber se existe uma tupla `('João', 15)` dentro dos valores de `dados`?

Comment: Não está claro se você quer validar os tipos de dados dentro das tuplas ou se você quer pesquisar nestas tuplas...

Comment: Imagina, tenho uma tupla com os seguintes dados: tuplo = ( (joao,39), (paulo,15), (andre,14), (simao,21) )   ««« agora o objetivo do programa é eu chegar a funcao.. e  escrever um nome qualquer e uma idade, SE e só SE esse par estiver no tuplo é que ele retorna verdade, se algum dos dados.. seja o nome ou idade, ou ambos não estiverem no tuplo, entao ele retorna o false.

Comment: Ou seja se eu agora chega-se e escrevesse verifica(('paulo',20))   ele devia retornar um false porque a idade n corresponde ao par no tuplo.

Comment: A sua pergunta dá a entender que você quer validar se os elementos da tupla principal são no formato `tuple(str, int)`. Sua pergunta: **Quero escrever uma função que recebe um argumento e devolve true se o argumento for um tuplo , onde o 1º é um nome (str) e o 2º é uma idade (int)**. Você poderia editar a pergunta para esclarecer melhor

Comment: Fernando, existe um chat nesta plataforma? posso explicar melhor para não spammar os comments

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85348/duvida-exercicio-python-tuplos

Comment: You must have 20 reputation on The Stack Exchange Network to talk here. Existe algum alternativo? posso mandar te email?

Comment: Você quer descobrir se a tupla passada na função `verfica` está contida na tupla  que contém seus dados. É isso?

Comment: O problema que eu tenho em mãos é o seguinte, pede para eu escrever uma function
em python que recebe um argumento de qq valor e devolve VERDADE se o argumento for 
um TUPLO de elementos pares (duplos de dois elementos), onde o 1 elemento é um nome (str) 
tal como eu disse e o 2 é a idade (int). Caso contrario RETURN false.

exemplo: verifica(('joao',39)) 
true (porque temos esse par no dados)

verifica(('joao',40))
false (porque temos um joao mas ele tem 39 anos.

Comment: Sua descrição diz uma coisa e seu exemplo diz outro. Na sua descrição fala para criar uma função que valide se o argumento é uma tupla no formato `tuple(str, int)` e no exemplo você está fazendo um "exists" na tupla. Você deveria editar sua pergunta para torná-la mais clara.

Comment: Você tem razão, eu estava a complicar.

Comment: neste caso, a sua resolução inicial estava correcta: def verifica(variavel):
    return all((
        isinstance(variavel, tuple),
        isinstance(variavel[0], str),
        isinstance(variavel[1], int)
    ))  é possivel retirar então os dados e o ciclo for e vai funcionar na mesma?

Comment: Estou complementando a resposta para verificar se o valor existe nas tuplas

Comment: Não precisa, o meu exemplo estava errado, eu estava a complicar.

Comment: A ideia é mesmo escrever a função verifica(('nome', idade))  onde o nome é um str e a idade é um int, se sim, da true, se nao da false. eu estou a tentar correr só a primeira parte do programa sem incluis os dados e o ciclo for, mas não da, é possivel?

Comment: Fernando, na resolução do matheus mais em baixo, como é que se acrescetam os argumentos? repara no exemplo que lhe dei, quero evitar "builtins.TypeError: verifica() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given"

Comment: a função `verifica()` recebe apenas 1 argumento, uma tupla. Se você quer testar várias tuplas faça um `for` e teste todas as tuplas dentro da sua sequência. O código da minha resposta faz isso.

Comment: No contexto do seu código, é possivel retirar os dados? e é possivel utilizar o return no for em vez do print? Outra voisa, o "d" representa o que exactamente?

Comment: def verifica(variavel):
    return all((
        isinstance(variavel, tuple),
        isinstance(variavel[0], str),
        isinstance(variavel[1], int)
    ))

for v in variavel:
    return(verifica(v))

Comment: da me erro: Syntax Error: 'return' outside function:

Comment: [Checa esse link](https://translate.google.com.br/#en/pt/return%20outside%20function)

Comment: Fernando, que o return esta fora da função eu entendi, qual é a syntax correcta para ter o return a funcionar dentro da função?

Comment: Fernando, o meu programa não pode utilizar prints, todos os exemplos apresentados tem, eu não sei aplicar devidamente o return, não conheço o suficiente a syntax. Esquece a minha questão inicial, o tuplo não é para estar definido dentro do programa de forma como escrevi. Deve antes testar uma sequencia de tuplos usando a função na shell. Podes demonstrar um exemplo com estas specs?  1ºnão pode ter prints. 2ºnao deve ter o tuplo definido com dados dentro da função 3º deve testar a sequencia na shell   exemplo: verifica(('paulo',19), ('maria',23),('joao',53))  «« retorna um true pk todos

Comment: os parametros da tupla cumprem os req de str e int

Answer (score 0):

Se eu entendi bem, você quer uma função que pegue o código e veja se é do tipo tuple, se for, pegar a posição 0 e ver se é string e a posição 1 e ver se é int...
Segue o código:

```
def verifica(variavel):
    #If para saber se é uma tupla
    if type(variavel) is tuple:
        #Caso seja tupla, vamos verificar se o primeiro elemento é str e o segundo int
        if (type(variavel[0]) is str) and (type(variavel[1]) is int):
            return True
        else:
            return False
    return False

verifica(('matheus',1))
```

PS: utilizei o python 2.7

Comment: matheus agradeço a contribuição. só falta uma nuance. tem que haver um tuplo com dados, tal como escrevi.. e quando cologo os dados na função, para alem da condição das variaveis que o programa que escreve faz, ele ainda tem que verificar se os dados nome mais idade estao no tuplo.

Comment: Matheus ignore o que escrevi, ao conversar com o fernando entendi que estava a complicar a minha necessidade, agora só tenho uma questão relativamente a sua resolução :  builtins.TypeError: verifica() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given, Não é possivel utilizar varios argumentos na função? ex: verifica((‘matheus’, 21), (‘andre’, 32), (’maria’, 17),
(’joaquim’, 20))

Comment: Do jeito que está é só pra aceitar uma tupla. o que vc pode fazer e jogar um for dentro da função e passar uma tupla com varios valores

Comment: é isso mesmo que eu preciso, o fernando ainda não me respondeu, mas no caso dele ele o usou o print, eu só posso usar return e no ciclo for, eu não entendo a variavel "d" « não se declara em lado nenhum?

Comment: for v in variavel:
    if type(variavel) is tuple:
        if (type(variavel[0]) is str) and (type(variavel[1]) is int):
            return True
        else:
            return False
    return False
  return(verifica(v))

Comment: Não consigo aplicar devidamente o ciclo for, continua a apresentar o mesmo erro.

Answer (score 0):

Use a função `isinstance` passando cada elemento e o tipo. Segue uma função que generaliza essa ideia:

```
def verificar_tipos(tupla, tipos):
    return all(isinstance(elemento, tipo) for elemento, tipo in zip(tupla, tipos))
```

Você utiliza dessa forma:

```
verificar_tipos(('joao', 23), (str, int)) # retorna True
verificar_tipos(('joao', 23), (str, str)) # retorna False
```

Se você tiver uma lista de tuplas, basta fazer um for chamando a `verificar_tipos` para cada uma delas:

```
def verifica(tuplas, tipos):
    for tupla in tuplas:
        if not verificar_tipos(tupla, tipos)
            return False
    return True
```

Você usaria assim:

```
verifica([('paulo',19), ('maria',23),('joao',53)])
```

Comment: Gabriel, grato pela contribuição. A minha função deve testar varios parametros de uma vez, tal como indiquei no exemplo ao fernando:  verifica(('paulo',19), ('maria',23),('joao',53)) «« retorna um true. O exemplo do matheus faz o que quero mas só para 1 parametro, quero ter varios, ja me disseram que devo usar um ciclo FOR, mas não sei corrigir a syntax para isso. Consegue ajudar?  nota: não pode usar prints, só returns.

Comment: @dominion Eu atualizei a minha resposta com um exemplo de código que faz o que você disse, mas devo alertar que a função desse site não é dar códigos prontos pra ti. Se você não sabe fazer um laço `for` em Python, deveria estudar mais sobre o assunto, e não pedir pra gente fazer tudo por ti.