# Filtrar elementos de uma tupla com base em um valor em determinado índice

Tags: python

Quero escrever uma função em Python, chamada separa, que recebe um tuplo tup cujos elementos são pares (duplos de 2 elementos), em que o 1º elemento é um nome (uma cadeia de caracteres) e o 2º elemento é uma idade (um inteiro), tal como descrito no exercício anterior.

A função deve devolver 1 tuplo com dois elementos:

- 1 tuplo com os elementos do tuplo original em que a idade é menor do que 18.
- 1 tuplo com os elementos do tuplo original em que a idade é maior ou igual a 18.
- A sua função deve verificar se o argumento recebido está correto (use a função do exercício 1 para fazer esta verificação). Se o argumento não estiver correto deve ser gerado um erro,  com a instrução raise ValueError(’separa: argumento incorrecto.’).

Exemplo:

```
>>> tup = (('Maria', 38), ('Miguel', 17), ('Tiago', 18), ('Sara', 19))
>>> menores, maiores = separa(tup)
>>> menores
(('Miguel', 17),)
>>> maiores
(('Maria', 38), ('Tiago', 18), ('Sara', 19))

>>> separa(())
((), ())

>>> separa((('Maria', 38), ('Miguel', 17), ('Tiago', 18), ('Sara', 19.7)))
              ….
builtins.ValueError: separa: argumento incorrecto.
```

Comment: O que você tentou? Fora copiar o enunciado da questão, teve alguma dificuldade?

Comment: E agora, com vocês, Celso Overflow do "Passa Cola e Responde Logo".

Comment: não estou percebendo como posso fazer.

Comment: Sousa, por gentileza, o SOpt funciona melhor quando as perguntas são mais generalistas e se aplicam de maneira ampla a audiência do site. Em outras palavras, "como resolver um exercício" não é uma boa pergunta. Copiar o enunciado também não. Precisa haver mais engajamento da sua parte em explicar, formatar e demonstrar o problema.

Nos mostre o que você _tentou_ fazer. Sumarize suas dúvidas, faça **perguntas**. Leia [isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) e [isto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para tentar adequar sua pergunta.

Comment: Isto foi o que eu fiz: def verifica(variavel):
    if isinstance(variavel, tuple):
        if isinstance(variavel[0], str) and isinstance(variavel[1], int):
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False

Comment: @sousa Por favor clique em **[edit]** e adicione o código na pergunta. Assim fica mais organizado (outros usuários não precisam ficar "caçando" informações nos comentários, toda a informação relevante fica na pergunta), e além disso fica mais legível, pois é possível formatar o código (veja [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) dicas de como formatar). Isso é ainda mais importante em Python, já que a indentação faz parte da sintaxe, e nos comentários não fica claro como está a indentação

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como validar se um valor é uma tupla possuindo uma string e um inteiro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/341085/como-validar-se-um-valor-%c3%a9-uma-tupla-possuindo-uma-string-e-um-inteiro)

Answer (score 4):

Se você tem uma tupla na forma

```
valores = (('Maria', 38), ('Miguel', 17), ('Tiago', 18), ('Sara', 19))
```

Você pode listar os itens que possui o segundo valor menor que 18 da seguinte forma:

```
menores = tuple(it for it in valores if it[1] < 18)
```

E maior ou igual a 18 de forma semelhante:

```
maiores = tuple(it for it in valores if it[1] >= 18)
```

Assim, considerando a função `verifica`, que foi definida no exercício anterior - isto é, vamos considerar que você já fez o exercício anterior e possui essa função funcionando (a implementação dela não faz parte desta pergunta), você pode escrever uma função na forma:

```
def separa(tuplo):
    if not verifica(tuplo):
        raise ValueError(’separa: argumento incorrecto.’)

    menores = tuple(it for it in tuplo if it[1] < 18)
    maiores = tuple(it for it in tuplo if it[1] >= 18)

    return (menores, maiores)
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Anderson, você ajudou imenso :)